# PostScript-like drawing in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, import, core-language

To illustrate by example, construct an equilateral triangle in PostScript:

```
0 0 moveto           %moveto origin
6 0 lineto           %construct first line segment
6 0 translate        %translate origin to current point
120 rotate           %rotate axes 120 degrees counterclockwise
6 0 lineto           %construct second line segment
closepath            %construct final line segment
```

Accurate and elegant.

Now concerning Mathematica, I have two questions.

1. Can a similar approach to construction be taken in Mathematica, somehow using say `JoinedCurve`?  (*Without* precomputing the points.)
2. Since Mathematica includes a decent PostScript import facility, can this actual PostScript code be fed into some function to produce the path as a Mathematica graphics object?

Comment: Have you seen `AnglePath[]`? BTW: once upon a time,before version 6, *Mathematica* had an explicit `PostScript[]` graphics primitive.

Comment: if you restrict yourself to such a simple example you could develop a rudimentary interpreter to convert the postscript to mathematica graphics. If your code uses `def`  procedures and nested graphics states and such it gets unwieldy though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As J.M. notes in a comment, `AnglePath` allows paths to be specified in relative terms instead of absolute terms:

```
Graphics[
  Line@AnglePath[{{60, 0°}, {60, 120°}, {60, 120°}}]
]
```

[image: hollow triangle]

Note that the figure had to be closed explicitly with an extra line.  We can remedy that by using `JoinedCurve`.

```
Graphics[
  JoinedCurve[Line@AnglePath[{{60, 0°}, {60, 120°}}], CurveClosed->True]
]
```

[image: hollow triangle]

We can emulate the Postscript code more closely by performing explicit translations and rotations, but it is not pretty:

```
Graphics[
  { Line[{{0, 0}, {60, 0}}]
  , Translate[{##}, {60, 0}]&[
      Rotate[{##}, 120°, {0, 0}]&[
        Line[{{0, 0}, {60, 0}}]
      , Translate[{##}, {60, 0}]&[
          Rotate[{##}, 120°, {0, 0}]&[
            Line[{{0, 0}, {60, 0}}]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

[image: hollow triangle]

Of course, *Mathematica* is well-suited to define our own domain-specific language to clean this up, but that is beyond the scope of this response.

---

**What about Postscript?**

We can get *Mathematica* to draw Postscript directly by adding minimal headers and footers around our code to make it an importable Encapsulated Postscript file (EPS):

```
$ps = "%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: -10 -10 70 70

0 0 moveto            %moveto origin
60 0 lineto           %construct first line segment
60 0 translate        %translate origin to current point
120 rotate            %rotate axes 120 degrees counterclockwise
60 0 lineto           %construct second line segment
closepath             %construct final line segment
stroke

showpage
%%EOF
";

ImportString[$ps, "EPS"]
```

[image: hollow triangle]

The generated graphics are in vector form, complete with corner caps and joins:

```
% // InputForm

(*
Graphics[{Thickness[0.0125], 
  Style[{JoinedCurve[{{{0, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}}, {{{10., 9.999999999999996}, {70., 
      10.}, {40.000000124354074, 61.96152429886217}}}, CurveClosed -> {1}]}, 
   CapForm["Butt"], JoinForm[{"Miter", 10.}], Thickness[0.008838834801470012]]}, 
 ImageSize -> {80., 80.}, PlotRange -> {{0., 80.}, {0., 80.}}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
*)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `ImportString` gives a raster though.

Comment: @george2079 I'm getting a graphics object (Mma 10.3).

Comment: The problem with constructing the path with those translated segments is that the result is not a joined path.  I did not think of trying `ImportString`; this is quite nice when there is a simple PostScript equivalent.  But I was really looking for `AnglePath`; new to me, and of course not in the Graphics Objects list.  So now we can `Graphics[JoinedCurve[{Line[AnglePath[{0, 120 \[Degree]}]]}, 
  CurveClosed -> True]]`.  Nice!

Comment: I incorporated your comments into the response.  Thanks.